# How to create a new dataframe by looping until a certain criteria is met

Tags: python, dataframe, for-loop, while-loop

Here is a dataframe

```
dataframe = {'Mon':[1,7,0,4,2,8],
             'Tue':[8,4,2,5,9,3],
             'Wed':[0,5,1,1,4,3],
             'Thu':[8,6,5,7,6,8],
             'Fri':[4,5,4,6,5,7],
             'index':['Lucy','Guzy','Lisa,'Kala','Lura','kim']}
```

That looks like:

```
index Mon Tue Wed Thu Fri
lucy  1   8   0   8   4
Guzy  7   4   5   6   5
Lisa  0   2   1   5   4
Kala  4   5   1   7   6
lura  2   9   4   6   5
kimi  8   3   3   8   7
```

I would like to use a **loop** to iterate over this dataframe selecting every nth row to create a new dataframe until the new dataframe has a length of 6.

This is what i've attempted but not sure how to proceed:
In this case n = 3

```
row = 0
for row in len(dataframe):
    row = row + 3
    if row
```

I don't care about efficiency and would like to use a loop to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First slice every three rows with `iloc[::3]`, then use `iterrows` to loop over them:

```
for idx,row in dataframe.iloc[::3].iterrows():
    print(f'row {idx}')
    print(row)
```

Output:

```
row 0
Mon         1
Tue         8
Wed         0
Thu         8
Fri         4
index    Lucy
Name: 0, dtype: object
row 3
Mon         4
Tue         5
Wed         1
Thu         7
Fri         6
index    Kala
Name: 3, dtype: object
```